# vitejs loading js file not correctly while typical web-server does

Tags: javascript, python, html, vite

consider the next `index.html` file(which loading a script which allows running python code inside HTML 'py-script' tags):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Vite App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./pyscript-runtime/pyscript.css"/>
  <script defer src="./pyscript-runtime/pyscript.js"></script>
  <py-config>
        - autoclose_loader: true
        - runtimes:
              - src: "./pyscript-runtime/pyodide.js"
                name: pyodide-0.20
                lang: python
    </py-config>
</head>
<body>
<py-script>
    print('hello world')
</py-script>
</body>
</html>
```

when serving this index.html file via a normal web server `/pyscript-runtime/pyscript.js` is being loaded as a script an the page loads correctly.

however, loading this HTML as an entry point from vite would result in injected `import <> from <>` at the top of the file, treating it as a module, resulting in the famous error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`:

[image]

I actually tried to load this script as a module from normal web server and it worked, while vite refuses to load this page correctly, and I'm having a hard time understanding why.

this is the source code, cloning and serving index.html would result in working page
https://github.com/Eliav2/pyscript-offline-example

loading the same index.html file as entry point from vite app would not work.

is there any reason why the same HTML file would be loaded differently from a web server and a development web server like vite?